# Printing to file from global array of chars in c

Tags: c

I am having a problem while trying to print to txt file from global array of char*.

My array is declared as

```
char* codes[256];
```

also i have a function that construct a string and returns it to after which that value is placed into this global array

```
char* printArr(int arr[], int n)
{

    char* code = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (n+1));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        code[i] = arr[i] + '0';
    }
    code[n] = '\0';

    return code;
}
```

after which I just simply place that value into that global array. After that I am trying to print that array values into a txt file like this :

```
void PrintToFile(char* outputFileName)
{

   FILE* f = fopen(outputFileName, "w+");

   int i;

   for (i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
   {
        //printf("%s\n", codes[i]);
        fprintf(f, "%s\n", codes[i]);
   }

   fclose(f);
}
```

But for some reason my txt file turns out blank.
Also without opened stream when I try to print to stdout i get those values but with both printf and fprintf I don't get anything out either on stdout or in txt file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: did it a number of times before without any problems and I don't think that is the problem here but thanks anyway

Comment: Is the attempt to open the file working? Try just printing a string literal test text to it.

Comment: nothins is printed out, even if i put fprintf(f, "%s\n", "test") and loop it 256 times still got empty

Comment: "Empty" as in zero bytes long, or "empty" as in "my text editor doesn't display any printable characters"?

Comment: file is zero bytes

Comment: You've not given us enough to work with here.  We ordinarily expect a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: don't know what more is it here to give everything else is working fine if you print to stdout you get data but can't print anything to file

Comment: We don't want "everything else".  We want minimal code to make a complete program that demonstrates the problem, and any input needed to cause the program to do so -- hence *complete* and *verifiable*.  Although this may contain excerpts of your program, such as the pieces you've already provided, it will not ordinarily be a subset of your program's code, as that typically is not *minimal*.  Follow the link in my previous comment if you require further clarification.